# you don't have appropriate permissions to perform this operation in quickblox

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, quickblox, groupchat

I am try to add or remove OccupantsIDs using following methods.

1)Add OccupantsIDs

```
objChatDialog.pushOccupantsIDs = newAddUserList

    QBRequest.update(objChatDialog, successBlock: { (QBResponse, QBChatDialog) in

    }, errorBlock: { (QBResponse) in
        appDelegate.hideLoader()
    })
```

2)Remove OccupantsIDs

```
        objChatDialog.pullOccupantsIDs = leaveGroupID
        QBRequest.update(objChatDialog, successBlock: { (objQBResponse, objQBChatDialog) in
        }, errorBlock: { (objQBResponse) in

        })
```

While i will use above code some time it will work and some time it will return error '**You don't have appropriate permissions to perform this operation**'.

NOTE: i am trying with the group owner user (**Which created group dialog**).

Comment: Please create an issue in our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk) and attach full logs.

Comment: already do in GitHub repo

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: I can not find any solution.

Comment: [This issue is resolved](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/767)